# Migrating Windows installation to NVME RAID

Tags: windows-10, drivers, raid, sata, windows-11

I had Windows 11 installed on an NVMe drive and I have another spare (identical) NVMe drive. My plan was to create a Windows system image of my installation, create a new NVMe RAID array in my BIOS and then restore the system image onto the new array.

I've managed to get up to restoring the system image, however, I'm unable to boot into Windows, as I run into a `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE` error message. After failing to boot a couple times I'm able to load successfully into recovery mode.

While in recovery mode, I realised that I wasn't able to access the system partition, and I quickly realised this is likely due to the AMD NVMe RAID drivers not being installed.

After attempting to install them using `pnputil -a rc{bottom, cfg, raid}.inf` the drivers were visible in the output of `pnputil -e` so I restarted but to no avail. Rebooting back into recovery the drivers were no longer visible in the `pnputil -e` output. I did realise that there were already AMD RAID drivers installed (as I had a SATA RAID setup going before), however, these drivers only work for SATA arrays, so I needed to install the new NVMe drivers which support both PCI and SATA.

After removing the SATA RAID drivers with `pnputil -d oemxx.inf` I restarted and attempted to install the drivers again using the same process but again to no avail, the drivers did not show up after another restart.

After creating a Windows installation USB, I booted into WinPE, opened the command prompt and then loaded the RAID drivers with `dvrload`, which showed both my NVMe and SATA RAID arrays sucessfully, and I was able to interact with the Windows installation. I then repeated the above process of uninstalling the old drivers and installing the new ones but this time using `dism /image:e:\ /{add,remove}-driver` with the same results.

I've also rebuilt the BCD on my EFI partition with no success.

I'd really appreciate if anyone had an idea of where I could go from here as I feel like I've tried everything! Thank you in advance.

- AMD Ryzen 5 3600
- ASUS PRIME X570-P
- AMD X570 RAID Drivers Version 9.3.0.266